# Is there any alternative In Java that may correspond to foreach that exists in some other languages like C#

Tags: java, foreach

Is there any alternative in Java that may correspond to `foreach{}` available in other languages such as C# or VB or the languages alike? It may sometimes, in some very specific circumstances be very useful and almost mandatory.

Can the following `while(){}` loop in Java be replaced with a foreach loop or some other concepts that may exist in Java and correspond to foreach?

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrayList.add("A");
        arrayList.add("B");
        arrayList.add("C");
        arrayList.add("D");
        arrayList.add("E");

        Iterator<String>it=arrayList.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
}
```

---

I went on a long search on Google but I couldn't.

Comment: First result on Google for "foreach in java" - [The For-Each Loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: Actually,my focus was on the keyword "foreach", therefore, I might not be able to see it.

Comment: Never assume keywords will be the same :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If an object implements `Iterable` or it is an array, then you can use the enhanced for-each loop (introduced in Java 5.0)

```
for(E e : MyCollection) {
    // stuff
}
```

If your example, you can do

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
list.add("D");
list.add("E");

for(String s : list) System.out.println(s);
```

Technically your example was using a non-parameterized list, so you would use

```
for(Object o : arrayList) System.out.println(o.toString());
```